# Accelerated OpenGL Mode not working on Windows 8 (driver issue)

Tags: windows-8, drivers, opengl, minecraft

I am trying to run a game called Minecraft but I am having some trouble with it. I was able to run it a month ago, but it recently stopped working. I have tried updating all of my drivers.

I ran the [Intel Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html), and was able to see this:

[image: An Intel device was detected but your operating system is not supported by this utility.]

I can't update my Intel drivers to the latest version because apparently Windows 8 is not supported.

Can anyone help? I am able to run Modern Warfare 2 without any issues, but Minecraft is not working.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to Windows 8?  Did you go to the `Download Center` and locate the software by hand?

Comment: Yes, I updated from 7 to 8. I installed an earlier version of the driver and it worked for some reason, so thanks for the answers.

Comment: Since you seem to not understand the reason for your question banned I will explain the downvote I issued for this question. In the screenshot you provided it tells you to go to the `Download Center` and the answer that worked for you was to download an earlier driver from `Download Center`. So it appears from an outsider you didn't try going to the `Download Center` before asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the latest driver for your graphics chipset:

- 32-bit: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22165
- 64-bit: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22167

Comment: I had to install earlier version of the driver, and it worked.